# Create a new variable which is weekly min/max values of another variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

How can I assign value 1 to variable **S** when the value of column **A** is highest within the week? Also, how to assign value 2 to variable **S** when the value of **B** is the minimum within the week. I am working with hourly data, indexed by datetime.
Here is how my dataframe looks like:

```
                 A       B      S
datetime            
6/14/2004 1:00  384.5   383.6   0
6/14/2004 2:00  384.3   382.3   0
6/14/2004 3:00  383.3   382.3   0
6/14/2004 4:00  383.3   382.6   0
6/14/2004 5:00  383.3   382.8   0
6/14/2004 6:00  383.3   382.5   0
6/14/2004 7:00  383.3   382.3   0
6/14/2004 8:00  383.8   382.3   0
6/14/2004 9:00  382.8   382.1   0
6/14/2004 10:00 382.6   382.1   0
```

I have tried using resampling weekly and getting the max value but I do not how to code this as it got more complicated than I initially thought. 
Here is how I would like my final data to look like.

```
                  A      B      S
datetime            
6/14/2004 1:00  384.5   383.6   0
6/14/2004 2:00  384.3   382.3   0
6/14/2004 3:00  383.3   382.3   0
6/14/2004 4:00  383.3   382.6   0
6/14/2004 5:00  383.3   382.8   0
6/14/2004 6:00  383.3   382.5   0
6/14/2004 7:00  383.3   382.3   0
6/14/2004 8:00  383.8   382.3   0
6/14/2004 9:00  382.8   382.1   0
6/14/2004 10:00 382.6   382.1   0
6/14/2004 11:00 382.5   381.8   0
6/14/2004 12:00 382.8   382.3   0
6/14/2004 13:00 383.1   382.3   0
6/14/2004 14:00 385.8   382.5   0
6/14/2004 15:00 385.1   383.6   0
6/14/2004 16:00 384.8   383.5   0
6/14/2004 17:00 384.8   382.5   0
6/14/2004 18:00 383.6   382.8   0
6/14/2004 19:00 383.8   382.8   0
6/14/2004 20:00 383.3   382.8   0
6/14/2004 21:00 383.1   382.6   0
6/14/2004 22:00 383.1   382.6   0
6/14/2004 23:00 383.1   382.6   0
6/15/2004 0:00  382.8   382.6   0
6/15/2004 1:00  383.3   382.6   0
6/15/2004 2:00  383.6   382.3   0
6/15/2004 3:00  383.8   382.5   0
6/15/2004 4:00  382.8   382.1   0
6/15/2004 5:00  383.0   382.1   0
6/15/2004 6:00  382.8   382.0   0
... ... ... ...
6/24/2004 20:00 402.8   401.8   0
6/24/2004 21:00 402.3   401.8   0
6/24/2004 22:00 402.3   401.8   0
6/24/2004 23:00 402.1   401.1   0
6/25/2004 0:00  402.1   401.8   0
6/25/2004 1:00  402.1   401.3   0
6/25/2004 2:00  402.1   400.1   0
6/25/2004 3:00  401.6   400.8   0
6/25/2004 4:00  401.5   400.8   0
6/25/2004 5:00  401.3   400.8   0
6/25/2004 6:00  401.1   400.6   0
6/25/2004 7:00  402.1   400.8   0
6/25/2004 8:00  402.1   400.6   0
6/25/2004 9:00  401.6   400.5   0
6/25/2004 10:00 401.8   400.8   0
6/25/2004 11:00 401.5   400.6   0
6/25/2004 12:00 401.3   400.1   0
6/25/2004 13:00 402.8   401.3   0
6/25/2004 14:00 402.8   401.0   **1**
6/25/2004 15:00 401.5   400.1   0
6/25/2004 16:00 401.6   400.6   0
6/25/2004 17:00 401.8   401.0   0
6/25/2004 18:00 402.1   400.8   0
6/25/2004 19:00 402.3   400.8   0
6/25/2004 20:00 402.6   401.6   0
6/25/2004 21:00 401.8   401.3   0
6/25/2004 22:00 401.8   400.6   0
6/28/2004 0:00  401.8   401.6   0
6/28/2004 1:00  402.3   401.6   0
6/28/2004 2:00  402.3   401.5   0
```

For the first week, column S would have value 1 in **6/18/2004 18:00** and value 2 in **6/15/2004 11:00**
For the second week, columns S would have value 1 in **6/25/2004 14:00** and value 2 in **6/21/2004 18:00**

I figured out four rules:

**1.** When A = max(A) within the current week, put value 1 in S. If the A maximum is not unique within the week, put 1 in S at the last occurrence of the maximum in A.

**2.** When B = min(B) within the current week, put value 2 in S. If the B minimum is not unique within the week, put 2 in S at the last occurrence of the minimum in B.

**3.** Repeat this over all weeks. The entire dataset may have 80k+ hourly data rows.

**4.** Within each week: if max(A) and min(B) occur at the same datetime index, leave the value 0 in S (no change).

**Here is the code to read the data:**

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7wl75rkzsqgkoj/dataset.csv?dl=1'

p = pd.read_csv(url)
p.set_index('datetime', drop=True, inplace=True)
p
```

And here is a picture explaining how I want the output to look like:
[image: Final dataframe explanation]

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]. don't post images, please copy/paste code and input data in format anyone can use to replicate your process.

Comment: I guess this was my first question...

Comment: Well, the image was more helpful than a long copy paste. Your question was well addressed. You could just have shorten your sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like @jrjc approach, but I think this can be done without some assignments, let's try this:

```
def f(x):
    x.loc[x['A'][::-1].idxmax(), 'S'] = 1
    lindx = x['B'][::-1].idxmin()
    x.loc[lindx, 'S'] = np.where(x.loc[lindx, 'S'] == 1, 0, 2)
    return x


p_out = p.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).apply(f)
```

Check outputs by looking only at non-zero values of S for p_out:

```
p_out[p_out.S.ne(0)]
```

Output:

```
                         A      B  S
datetime                            
2004-06-15 11:00:00  382.0  381.1  2
2004-06-18 18:00:00  395.8  394.1  1
2004-06-21 18:00:00  394.8  392.1  2
2004-06-25 14:00:00  402.8  401.0  1
2004-06-28 14:00:00  404.6  402.3  1
2004-06-29 17:00:00  394.5  390.3  2
```

Comment: this is great! Really helpful! Thanks a ton! It took me some time to check as I wanted to make sure that the indexing on the week number wasn't creating any issues when using data from more than 1 year.

Comment: How do you check for ties with this solution (rule #4)?

Comment: Ah....jrjc makes a great point.  I am not checking for ties.   I'll add that logic in a bit.

Comment: thanks, look forward to it. I will be happy to accept it as the solution if that is taken care of.

Comment: Updated solution.   Happy coding!  Thanks @jrjc for pointing out error in logic.

Answer (score 3):

So I reduced the size of the dataframe so we can see something and I added a column week ("w") so we can better check.

First of all, you need to set the type of your index as a datetime object so you can access the date properties, such as week to groupby on.

```
p.index = pd.to_datetime(p.index)
p["w"] = p.index.week 

p                                                                      
                         A      B  S   w
datetime                                
2004-06-14 01:00:00  384.5  383.6  0  25
2004-06-14 09:00:00  382.8  382.1  0  25
2004-06-14 17:00:00  384.8  382.5  0  25
2004-06-15 01:00:00  383.3  382.6  0  25
2004-06-15 09:00:00  382.3  381.6  0  25
2004-06-15 17:00:00  388.6  384.6  0  25
2004-06-16 01:00:00  387.3  387.1  0  25
2004-06-16 09:00:00  388.8  387.6  0  25
2004-06-16 17:00:00  384.5  382.6  0  25
2004-06-17 01:00:00  384.6  383.6  0  25
2004-06-17 09:00:00  385.6  384.0  0  25
2004-06-17 17:00:00  386.8  386.0  0  25
2004-06-18 01:00:00  388.6  387.3  0  25
2004-06-18 09:00:00  387.5  385.8  0  25
2004-06-18 17:00:00  395.8  394.1  0  25
2004-06-21 02:00:00  394.3  392.8  0  26
2004-06-21 10:00:00  393.3  392.3  0  26
2004-06-21 18:00:00  394.8  392.1  0  26
2004-06-22 02:00:00  394.6  393.0  0  26
2004-06-22 10:00:00  394.0  392.6  0  26
2004-06-22 18:00:00  395.3  393.8  0  26
2004-06-23 02:00:00  394.3  393.6  0  26
2004-06-23 10:00:00  395.8  395.0  0  26
2004-06-23 18:00:00  394.6  393.6  0  26
2004-06-24 02:00:00  394.6  393.1  0  26
2004-06-24 10:00:00  397.8  394.8  0  26
2004-06-24 18:00:00  401.3  400.6  0  26
2004-06-25 02:00:00  402.1  400.1  0  26
2004-06-25 10:00:00  401.8  400.8  0  26
2004-06-25 18:00:00  402.1  400.8  0  26
2004-06-28 03:00:00  402.3  401.5  0  27
2004-06-28 11:00:00  402.1  400.8  0  27
2004-06-28 19:00:00  400.3  399.1  0  27
2004-06-29 03:00:00  399.6  399.1  0  27
2004-06-29 11:00:00  397.1  395.3  0  27
2004-06-29 19:00:00  392.3  391.0  0  27
2004-06-30 03:00:00  392.3  391.8  0  27
2004-06-30 11:00:00  393.6  393.1  0  27
2004-06-30 19:00:00  393.5  391.3  0  27
```

then, you need to define your function that you will apply on each week:

```
def minmax(grp): 
    Amax = grp.A[::-1].idxmax() # reverse your Series since you want the last occurence, and idxmax return the first in case of tie 
    grp.loc[Amax, "S"] = 1  
    Bmin = grp.B[::-1].idxmin()
    if Bmin != Amax:  
        grp.loc[Bmin, "S"] = 2
    else:
        grp.loc[Bmin, "S"] = 0 # no change
    return grp
```

and then groupby on each week per year and apply the function:

```
p.groupby([p.index.week, p.index.year]).apply(minmax)                                 
                         A      B  S   w
datetime                                
2004-06-14 01:00:00  384.5  383.6  0  25
2004-06-14 09:00:00  382.8  382.1  0  25
2004-06-14 17:00:00  384.8  382.5  0  25
2004-06-15 01:00:00  383.3  382.6  0  25
2004-06-15 09:00:00  382.3  381.6  2  25
2004-06-15 17:00:00  388.6  384.6  0  25
2004-06-16 01:00:00  387.3  387.1  0  25
2004-06-16 09:00:00  388.8  387.6  0  25
2004-06-16 17:00:00  384.5  382.6  0  25
2004-06-17 01:00:00  384.6  383.6  0  25
2004-06-17 09:00:00  385.6  384.0  0  25
2004-06-17 17:00:00  386.8  386.0  0  25
2004-06-18 01:00:00  388.6  387.3  0  25
2004-06-18 09:00:00  387.5  385.8  0  25
2004-06-18 17:00:00  395.8  394.1  1  25
2004-06-21 02:00:00  394.3  392.8  0  26
2004-06-21 10:00:00  393.3  392.3  0  26
2004-06-21 18:00:00  394.8  392.1  2  26
2004-06-22 02:00:00  394.6  393.0  0  26
2004-06-22 10:00:00  394.0  392.6  0  26
2004-06-22 18:00:00  395.3  393.8  0  26
2004-06-23 02:00:00  394.3  393.6  0  26
2004-06-23 10:00:00  395.8  395.0  0  26
2004-06-23 18:00:00  394.6  393.6  0  26
2004-06-24 02:00:00  394.6  393.1  0  26
2004-06-24 10:00:00  397.8  394.8  0  26
2004-06-24 18:00:00  401.3  400.6  0  26
2004-06-25 02:00:00  402.1  400.1  0  26
2004-06-25 10:00:00  401.8  400.8  0  26
2004-06-25 18:00:00  402.1  400.8  1  26
2004-06-28 03:00:00  402.3  401.5  1  27
2004-06-28 11:00:00  402.1  400.8  0  27
2004-06-28 19:00:00  400.3  399.1  0  27
2004-06-29 03:00:00  399.6  399.1  0  27
2004-06-29 11:00:00  397.1  395.3  0  27
2004-06-29 19:00:00  392.3  391.0  2  27
2004-06-30 03:00:00  392.3  391.8  0  27
2004-06-30 11:00:00  393.6  393.1  0  27
2004-06-30 19:00:00  393.5  391.3  0  27
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks a ton, @jrjc! This helped but I guess there is an issue with it. It misses some instances, mainly the min values.

Comment: @Silviu, could you be more precise ? Edit your question and add a short example that you think my solution failed at.

Comment: I don't know what happens. On the subset I shared, it works fine. But when I run it on the entire dataset, it is not working. Try it yourself: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pr08n0i8enuqen/datasetf.csv?dl=1'                   It generates 106 values in S. But it should generate 1513.

Comment: try to find a week where it is missing.

Comment: In the dataset 'dropbox.com/s/4pr08n0i8enuqen/datasetf.csv?dl=1', there are 756 weeks. In principle, there should be 1 high and 1 low value for each week, meaning I should expect 1512 values in S. When I run your script, it only gives 106. Second, the script does not give the same results when ran on a larger dataset. You can compare the output for the two dataset I shared